# How to get js-cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, setcookie

I have a code for setting a cookie from js-cookie

```
Cookies.set("currentCity", selected ? JSON.stringify(selected.city) : "", {
            domain: `.${process.env.DOMAIN}`,
})
```

When I try to get cookie on change of currentCity variable

```
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('All Cookies' ,Cookies.get())
  }, [currentCity])
```

I have the following in console

```
_pk_id.10.1fff: "7f704b7a9d967f1e.1577256464.0.1577265589.."
```

Also when I didnt set a Cookie (just removed Cookies.set)

I have the same in console.log on get Cookie

```
_pk_id.10.1fff: "7f704b7a9d967f1e.1577256464.0.1577265589.."
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is `_pk_id.10.1fff` the same Cookie which I have set at first time ?

Comment: Try clearing all the cookies before you run. Also log `selected` and `JSON.stringify(selected.city)` variables before Cookie.set line. Possibly when you removed the Cookie.set and logged, it is still logging the same value because cookie was already set in the first iteration and not removed

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the cookie value to currentCity everytime without clearing its values (in case you didn't close your browser) , perhaps removing the cookie first might solve your problem.

Here's a suggestion :

```
const domain = { domain: `.${process.env.DOMAIN}` };
if (selected === true) {
  if (Cookies.get("currentCity")) {
    Cookies.remove("currentCity");
    Cookies.set("currentCity", JSON.stringify(selected.city),domain);
  }
} else {
  Cookies.set("currentCity", "", domain);
}
```